# How to include apostrophe in Regex match

Tags: regex, python-3.x

The function needs to create Acronyms. 
Example Input-GNU Image Manipulation Program.   output-GIMP 
        Input- First In, First Out    output-FIFO
        Input- Halley's Comet  output - HSC, however it should be HC
The code is the following

```
def abbreviate(words):
    acroynm=''
    b=words.replace('_', '')
    d=re.findall(r'\w+|^\s',b)
    for char in d:
        acroynm+=(char[0])
    return acroynm.upper()
```

The problem is that regex doesn't include the apostrophe, and takes the rest of the word after the apostrophe as a separate word.

How I can change the Regex code so apostrophe will be included?

Comment: `[^\W]` is **exactly** the same of `\w`.

Comment: Could you give an example with apostrophe and expected result?

Comment: example with apostrophe input--Halley's Comet output-- HSC, however it should be HC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you want:

```
import re

arr = [
    'GNU Image Manipulation Program',
    'First In, First Out',
    'ab\'c def',
]

def abbreviate(words):
    L = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)([a-zA-Z])', words)
    return "".join(L).upper()

for s in arr:
    print abbreviate(s)
```

**Output:**

```
GIMP
FIFO
AD
```

**Regex explain:**

```
(?<!\S)         # negative lookbehind, zero length assertion that checks there is no non-spaces before 
                   # (it means there can be a space or beginning of string)
([a-zA-Z])      # group 1, a letter
```

Comment: Yes, the outputs are right, however I wanted to understand the process. SO if it is not hard for you can you  explain the regex components, especially the first parentheses part